# Put event-endler onsubmit in my javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, onsubmit

I've this registration form. I think it works great but is it possible to somehow get the  event-handler onsubmit in the JS page instead?

I mean...

Can i have a id on my form and put the onsubmit in the JS for example `document.getElementById("form id").onsubmit();` ?

*Html*

```
<form onsubmit="return ValidateForm()">
<!-- Newsletter registration  -->
<b>Få vårat nyhetsbrev!</b>
Namn: <input id="name" type="text" name="name" /><br>
Email:<input id="email" type="text" name="email" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Prenumenera" >
</form>
```

*JS*

```
function ValidateForm()
{
    var name = document.getElementById ("name");

    if (name.value.length == 0) {
        alert ("Enter a name.");
        return false;
    }
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

    if (!filter.test(email)) {
        alert("Invalid Email");
        return false;
    }
    alert("Thank you!");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can, just do

```
document.getElementById("form id").addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    if (!ValidateForm()) e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

and place the script after the form in the DOM

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xp6AF/1/)

Comment: That is great, i just have problem where too put it. Didn't understand what you ment "after the form in the DOM" Thanks

Comment: On your fiddle form still have onsubmit="return ValidateForm() in html and not id? Sorry for newby question but Im new:)

Comment: Oops, copy pasted, and then forgot to change it. Updated the fiddle.

Comment: It is weird, it works great in your fiddle but not in my code. Even if i copy the code to new documents the "Alert popups" doesn't work. hmmm wonder what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: And you're placing it **after** the elements in the DOM, as in the script tag that contains the javascript goes after the form and any other elements accessed in the javascript.

Comment: I'am sorry but what do you mean with after the elements in the DOM? I tried everything i could think of but i can 't understand. When i copy/paste your code it still doesn't work.. any last ideas what I am doing wrong? Greets

Comment: I mean place the script tag after the HTML, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/xp6AF/2/**

Comment: Aha, i understand now. Thank you for patient!